# VB.Net append text file into access mdb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a VB.NET program that reads a text file and inserts the data into a mdb. The text file is a stream string that is not possible to split, so I need to use substring to get the different fields. The way that the code works now is that the string is substring, then put inserted into different fields in the mdb. But the speed is too slow.

Example: `12345678TomChan 80`

- The first eight digits are the ID
- The folowing 10 digits are the name
- The final two digits are mark

This is the string layout and it has about 20000 records.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: would love to see your code and then comment

Comment: Show example of text file

Comment: the text file is like this

Comment: 12345678TomChan   80          the first eight digit is id,  then folowing 10 digits is name, the final two digits is mark, this is ony one line of record and it has about 20000 records, so I want to find a faster way

Comment: show your parsing and database update code.

Comment: first I use array to store the content of the text array1 = file.getfromtxt (dir, text.txt)  then use for loop to get each row data and substring id = array1(i).substring(0，8).trim, finally usr sql insert command to insert, and then loop the other line

Comment: Not enough. You complain because your code is slow, but we are not able to see your monitor, how can we help you? Edit your question and add the exact code you have written to parse the text file and add records to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use a schema.ini file and a straight import to MS Access.

```
[imp.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=FixedLength
Col1=ID  Char Width 8
Col2=AName  Char Width 10
Col3=Mark Char Width 2
```

SQL

```
SELECT * INTO Imp FROM [Text;DATABASE=Z:\docs].[imp.txt]
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thx, it is ok but i have the date in the txt file, the format is yyyymmdd,eg. 20120120. but it cannot import in mdb. in the schema.ini, i use updateon date width 8. i want to ask how to import the date？？ thx！

Comment: Are you saying that the textfile is named for the date, eg, 20130602.txt, or are you saying that your example above is incomplete? If it is the file name, you can run a query to append a column and update it with the date. If you example is incomplete, please update your post.